# Why is Apache not starting?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-squeeze

Here is my error log:

```
[Sat Jul 14 21:39:21 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 14 21:39:21 2012] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
[Sat Jul 14 21:39:21 2012] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
[Sat Jul 14 21:39:23 2012] [alert] No active workers found... Apache is exiting!
[Sat Jul 14 21:39:36 2012] [warn] pid file /var/run/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Jul 14 21:39:36 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 14 21:39:36 2012] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
[Sat Jul 14 21:39:36 2012] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
[Sat Jul 14 21:39:38 2012] [alert] No active workers found... Apache is exiting!
[Sat Jul 14 21:43:17 2012] [warn] pid file /var/run/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Jul 14 21:43:17 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 14 21:43:17 2012] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
```

How do I fix this and what's wrong with it?

Comment: You can answer your own question; it's a fundamental part of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the solution:

Add `ulimit -s 512` to your apache `envvars` file (try `/etc/apache2/envvars`).

Sources:

- [Apache2 is not starting my webserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/137769/apache2-is-not-starting-my-webserver?rq=1)
- [Setting Apache2 PATH environment variable](https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable)