# Cannot open shared object file when restarting httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, mod-wsgi

```
$ /etc/init.d/httpd restart

Starting httpd: httpd: 
Syntax error on line 205 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: 
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
```

file: httpd.conf

```
..
205: LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Any ideas in how can I correct this error or how to share the file: `mod_wsgi.so`, in order to be loaded and used by apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be for the following problems #

- Your copy of mod_wsgi is compiler against a different version of
  python than what you have.
- Your copy of libpython shared object file    isn't in apache's
  library path

Following links may help you #

- [googlecode](http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/InstallationIssues.wiki)
- [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable)
- [kunclehead](http://drknucklehead.wordpress.com/category/django-2/)

Comment: It is unlikely to be either. The error suggests that the mod_wsgi.so file simply does not exist.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @GrahamDumpleton Sir, and for further i have shared the links

Answer (score 1):

The error says that:

```
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

does not exist.

Run:

```
ls -las /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

to prove whether it does or does not. If it doesn't then install mod_wsgi.

If it does exist, then validate if version of Python it is compiled against exists and/or is findable.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library